Do we really need a practice tag?
In a recent question, a new tag practice appeared. Nicely, tag info is written too;

For questions regarding practical usage, development, and study of cryptographic schemes and protocols.

Do we really need this kind of generic tag? Encryption is already cover this.

Regardless of the usefulness of the tag, I think the term should be "applied-cryptography"  rather than "practice" (or "practical-cryptography").

Weirdly the tag is created in response to David Carey who is suggesting a far better (and less generic) tag be created - 'responsible-disclosure'.

@ModalNest FYI. here in meta, the up and down votes don't make points. It just behaves like a selection. If you think we shouldn't have this tag then upvote No and maybe downvote yes, too. We need 5 or 6 difference to arrive a decision.

"Practical usage," "development," and the "study of cryptography" are quite different. "Practical usage" = applied cryptography; "development" = developing primitives and protocols; "the study of cryptographic schemes and protocols" = "studying cryptography" or "studying cryptology."

There are people who came to this website with an honest question about how to approach the study of cryptography, or even a specific area of it, and they were basically turned away. I disagreed with that.  Who else could ever offer good advice on such questions than some of the people here?  Perhaps guide such questioners to chat.  Or, if there is going to be a tag that covers the study of cryptography, then such questions will now have legitimacy.

No, we don't need this tag;

It is too generic to use.

Community please fill reasons

Change it to cryptography-development, and change the tag info as well.
I do accept the proposition that "practice" is way too generic, but I think we do need a tag for the human intellect aspect of cryptography.

Yes, we need this tag;
Community please fill reasons
